# Accessing reference to class

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

Given :

```
function GameManager(){...};

GameManager.prototype.draw = function(){
    this.world.removeChildren() // <-- Error is here; "this" is PIXI.Sprite, not GameManger
}

GameManager.prototype.text = function(func){
    let spr = new PIXI.Sprite();
    spr.pointerup = func;
    this.world.addChild(spr);
}
```

I want to access "GameManager" when I call

```
this.text(this.drawgame);
```

in

```
this.world.removeChildren() //GameManager.prototype.draw
```

Instead of that I'm getting `PIXI.Sprite` because I call `spr.pointerup = func`

Is there any possibility to get reference of `GameManager` instead of `PIXI.Sprite`?

I don't want to use global variable

Comment: `this.text(this.drawgame.bind(this));`

Comment: @JonasW. thank you, it's working, add this as answer so I can mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 this.text(this.drawgame);
```

Here you are loosing the context. You beed to *bind* the context:

```
 this.text(this.drawgame.bind(this));
```